# MySQL PDO prepared statement updating columns incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've got logic in my php to automatically build update/insert queries based on the class defined.
It is generating the following sql/params:
sql:

```
UPDATE `sessions` SET 
`date`=:date,
`client`=:client,
`rate`=:rate,
`notes`=:notes,
`location`=:location,
`includedimagecount`=:includedimagecount,
`paid`=:paid,
`includedimagesdownloaded`=:includedimagesdownloaded,
`additionalpaid`=:additionalpaid,
`additionalimageprice`=:additionalimageprice,
`readyforclient`=:readyforclient,
`additionalimagesdownloaded`=:additionalimagesdownloaded 
WHERE uid=:_id_
```

params:

```
[date:"2021-11-22 22:34:00",
client:"D3036CCD-D3C1-44B0-B729-B9B7D72769D9",
rate:"85",
notes:"",
location:"nowhere",
includedimagecount:"10",
paid:1,
includedimagesdownloaded:1,
additionalpaid:0,
additionalimageprice:"4",
readyforclient:1,
additionalimagesdownloaded:0,
_id_:"F23E8D6B-2ED7-4F7A-B59B-42CBDD7B4A5B"]
```

And for some reason I can't figure out, after this runs - my db shows columns `additionalPaid`, and `AdditionalImagesDownloaded` as `1`, even though those values are clearly 0 in the update params.

Here is the schema for the table if it helps...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `Uid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Client` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Rate` float NOT NULL,
  `Notes` text,
  `Location` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IncludedImageCount` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `AdditionalImagePrice` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `Paid` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `IncludedImagesDownloaded` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `AdditionalPaid` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `ReadyForClient` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `AdditionalImagesDownloaded` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sessions_uid_uindex` (`Uid`),
  KEY `sessions_client_fk` (`Client`)
```

When I run the same query directly in datagrip (still using the value placeholders) it works as expected.

**EDIT**

I am able to get around this issue by sending in a smaller object with *only* the column I actually want to update (and id). But this is an open source framework, and I need to make sure this feature works as intended.

**EDIT 2**

[Here is the code](https://github.com/Nixon-Joseph/TemplatedPHPMVC/blob/152ea2d10e253232302b1fe7761540445728f44c/src/abstract/Repo.php#L402-L465) in question.
The object being passed in is an instance of a class with 1 to 1 match on properties/table columns.

**EDIT 3**

I have tried it with `:` in the parameter array as well (to match the query), and got the same result.

Comment: We might need to see the PHP code to answer your question.

Comment: Of course, adding a link to the question now!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing their datatype from bit to tinyint(1). bit usually fail me sometimes.

Comment: I have ended up doing that already just to get it to work. I'm not overly concerned with it on this particular project, but the base code I have - I'm writing as a public framework. And I just want to make sure it's effective and reliable. If there's something I can do code-side to fix it for bits I'd like to. - Note, I haven't tried switching to the `bind` syntax instead of the param array yet.

Comment: Well, tinyint(1) will work like bit as well, passing 0 or 1 will be read as true or false as well with tinyint(1)